# How to call a virtual function from within a derived class function

Tags: c++, linker-errors, virtual-functions, undefined-reference, derived-class

I'm trying to call a virtual function from within a derived class function using a pointer to the derived class. In the base class it's a pure virtual function, but the derived class defines it. But, I get a linker error saying that the function isn't defined. The compiler is aware of the definition, because when I comment out the definition it complains that the derived class is abstract.

My code is more complicated than below, but in trying to isolate the bug I've whittled it down to the exact bits that are generating the linker error. Any ideas?

```
struct Derived;

struct Base
{
  virtual Derived*func( Base*)=0;
  virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived*func(Base*)
  {
    // do stuff here
    return nullptr; // actual code returns a non-null
  }

  Derived*operate( Derived*arg)
  {
    // do stuff here
    return Base::func(static_cast<Base*>(arg));
  }
};

int main()
{
  Derived *pt = new Derived();
  pt->operate(nullptr); // linker error
  pt->func(nullptr);    // okay, compiles and runs as expected
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call func without qualification. Qualified lookup suppresses virtuality.

Comment: When you use `somefunc() = 0` it usually means "This base doesn't define this func, but all derived must define it". More about abstract class and pure virtual function [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class)

Answer (score 2):

By doing:

```
Base::func(static_cast<Base*>(arg));
```

You're calling the `Base` version of `func()`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Instead, you probably mean to call `Derived::func()`, which you can refer to as just `func()`

```
func(static_cast<Base*>(arg));
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please accept this answer by clicking the green check mark next to the answer and mark this question as solved. Or, you could mark the other answer as the accepted answer if you think it better solves our problem. Additionally, please feel free to upvote *any* answers you found useful. This will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the base function that you have defined as pure virtual. The code should look like:

```
struct Derived;

struct Base
{
  virtual Derived*func( Base*)=0;
  virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived*func(Base*) override
  {
    // do stuff here
    return nullptr; // actual code returns a non-null
  }

  Derived*operate( Derived*arg)
  {
    // do stuff here
    return this->func(arg);
  }
};

int main()
{
  Derived *pt = new Derived();
  pt->operate(nullptr); // linker error
  pt->func(nullptr);    // okay, compiles and runs as expected
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don’t need the `this->`.

Comment: Thanks, that fix worked. In this short example I don't need this->, but I do in the full code that I'm working with.